# How to center a UICollectionView when it is tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` and it has quite a lot of `UICollectionViewCells` on it. I want to scroll the cell to the centre of the `UICollectionView` when it is tapped. My concern is that even if I tap the last or the top cell it should move to the centre of the collection view.

I have tried setting the `contentInsets` and offsets but they don't seem to work. I think I will have to change the content size on selection and change it back to original when the scrolling begins.

Comment: Check my edited answer, i added some changes to it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Setting contentInsets should give some extra space around first and last cells:

```
CGFloat collectionViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(collectionView.bounds);
[collectionView
  setContentInset:
   UIEdgeInsetsMake(collectionViewHeight/2, 0, collectionViewHeight/2, 0) ];
  // nb, those are top-left-bottom-right
```

After you should call:

```
[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:selectedItemPath
    atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically
    animated:YES];
```

It's important to pass correct scroll position: UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically

This should center tapped item properly.

**EDIT**

It's really strange, but after setting UIEdgeInsets to collection view method scrollToItemAtIndexPath does not works properly, so i make some modification:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat collectionViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.frame);
    [collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(collectionViewHeight / 2, 0, collectionViewHeight / 2, 0)];

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0,  cell.center.y - collectionViewHeight / 2);
    [collectionView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
}
```

it works fine for me.

Comment: Typo: `UIEdgeInstetsMake` should be `UIEdgeInsetsMake`.

Comment: I get "no visible interface for UICollectionView declares the selector setContentInsets"

Comment: @shim, oh, yes, it was a typo - should be setContentInset.

Comment: The issue with scrollToItemAtIndexPath + using Inset happens only when the cell is visible. I ended up using both workaround from Mikhail and scrollToItemAtIndexPath, depending on if the cell was visible or not. (The workaround works only with visible cells since cellForItemAtIndexPath would return nil to non visible cells)

Comment: Yes, for some reason, setting the `contentInset` and `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` don't work together. I think it's a bug

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 3** solution for scrolling and centering screen to make the tapped item visible:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
}
```

This doesn't add inset above or under the `collectionView`!

Comment: What if I want to center align first and last selected cell.

Answer (score 10):

It seems that this bug is caused by a bad interaction between the scroll view's `contentInset` and  `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.  In my testing, setting `layout.sectionInset` rather than `collectionView.contentInset` eliminated the problem.

Based on the accepted answer above, I would eliminate the workaround, and change:

```
[collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(collectionViewHeight / 2, 0, collectionViewHeight / 2, 0)];
```

to

```
[layout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(collectionViewHeight / 2, 0, collectionViewHeight / 2, 0)];
```

Comment: Amazing solution that fixes the workaround from Mikhail. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` method to put selected(tapped) cell to center position in UICollectionView

```
[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                       atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                               animated:true];
```

You can use `UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically` for vertical centered position

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** Solution

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
   // collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true) - If you are using vertical collectionView. 
}
```